# Cannot get Radio Button Value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a personality assessment page. However, I am seriously stuck and at this point, I cannot even understand where I went wrong. (Psychology student here, so this world is new to me.)

```
<form action="answer.html" method="get" class="personality_form" id="personality_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<tr>
  <td>Statement1</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Statement2</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Statement3</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st3" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st3" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st3" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Statement4</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st4" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st4" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st4" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Statement5</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st5" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st5" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st5" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="4"><button type="submit" onclick="get();">Get Results</button></th>
</tr>
  </form>
```

Now I am adding here following script:

```
function get() {
    var res1 = document.getElementsByName("st1").value;
    var res2 = document.getElementsByName("st2").value;
    var x = res1 + res2;
    if (x < 0) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

And answer.html consists of

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

I cannot seem to get the value no matter how hard I try. I've tried doing `id="st1_1"` and `getElementById`, but it still won't do it.

Any suggestions or ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: is your above HTML form & answer.html page same or different files?

Comment: `getElementsByName` will return you an array of elements and you have to choose one element among them.

Comment: `getElementsByName` will get element by its name like `div, span, p` and you are trying it from attribute name.  please jump to jquery...!

Comment: goga I have posted working fiddle with some essential description which may probably helpful for future.

Comment: Someone's doing drive-by downvoting without explaining why. Maybe cut that out because it's not helpful.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns a [live nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) so you can't immediately grab the value. You need to iterate over the nodelist (or get the node you want using array notation) and then add the values.

However, what you might find easier is to use `querySelectorAll` to pick up *all* the checked buttons (`document.querySelectorAll(":checked")`) and iterate over those instead, making sure that you convert the string value to a number on each iteration when you add the values together.

```js
function get() {
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll(":checked");
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
    total += Number(checked[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = total;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', get, false);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Statement1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="na" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="agg" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Statement2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="na" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="agg" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>Get!</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This has helped me the whole lot! Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`, so there are multiple elements. As a result, it doesn't have a `value` property so `res1` and `res2` are `undefined`.

Try changing `document.getElementsByName("st1").value` to `document.querySelector("[name=\"st1\"]:checked").value`. If you get an error message like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" then it means that none of the inputs with the name "st1" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to James Long's answer,
Open the console on the webpage and type

```
document.getElementsByName("st1");
```

You will get
 `[<input type=​"radio" name=​"st1" class=​"dis" value=​"-1">​, <input type=​"radio" name=​"st1" class=​"na" value=​"0">​, <input type=​"radio" name=​"st1" class=​"agg" value=​"1">​]`

This indicates that you the above code returns an array. Now to select either of the `<input>` tags, you can use `document.getElementsByName("st1")[0]` which will select the first `<input>`.

To find out which input/s have been selected, iterate over the inputs and find the total sum. If you changed your values to

```
  <input type="radio" name="st#" class="dis" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="st#" class="na" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="st#" class="agg" value="4">
```

Then if the sum is 1, then first one is selected, if it is 2, then second is selected, if 3 then first two were selected, if 4 then third is selected, if 5 then first and third, 6 then second and third, 7 then all three.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function get() {
   
    var res1 = document.querySelector('input[name="st1"]:checked').value;

    var res2 = document.querySelector('input[name="st2"]:checked').value;

     console.log("res1="+res1);
     console.log("res2="+res2);
     
   var x = parseInt(res1) + parseInt(res2);
   // if (x < 0) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = x;
   // }
}
```

```html
<form method="get" class="personality_form" id="personality_form">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Statement1</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st1" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Statement2</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st2" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Statement3</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st3" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st3" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st3" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Statement4</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st4" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st4" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st4" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Statement5</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st5" class="dis" value="-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st5" class="na" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="st5" class="agg" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="4"><button type="button" onclick="get();">Get Results</button></th>
</tr>
</table>
  </form>
  
  <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You should add some commentary to explain exactly what you changed and why.

Comment: This has helped me the whole lot! Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score -1):

Please review working code this may help to resolve an issue. You should not use both "onClick() on submit button" and "OnSubmit on form post" at a time.

> click()

This method is a shortcut for in the first two variations and  in the third. The click event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, and the mouse button is pressed and released. Any HTML element can receive this event. click() event bind with a mouse. There are multiple events available for the mouse.

> submit()

submit() This method is a shortcut for .on( "submit", handler ) in the first variation, and .trigger( "submit" ) in the third. This method belongs to form event. There are also more events which are specifically bound with HTML form only.

The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to  elements. Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit , , or , or by pressing Enter when certain form elements have focus.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".personality_form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getData();
  });

  function getData() {
    var res1 = $("input[name='st1']").val();
    var res2 = $("input[name='st2']").val();
    var x = parseInt(res1) + parseInt(res2);
    if (x < 0) {
      $('.result').html(x);
    }
  }

  function validateForm() {
    return true;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" class="personality_form" id="personality_form">
  <tr>
    <td>Statement1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st1" class="dis" value="-1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st1" class="na" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st1" class="agg" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Statement2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st2" class="dis" value="-1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st2" class="na" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st2" class="agg" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Statement3</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st3" class="dis" value="-1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st3" class="na" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st3" class="agg" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Statement4</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st4" class="dis" value="-1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st4" class="na" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st4" class="agg" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Statement5</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st5" class="dis" value="-1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st5" class="na" value="0">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="st5" class="agg" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">
      <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">Get Results</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
</form>

<div class="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery when the OP isn't?

Comment: jquery gives better features and options to access and manipulate HTML and javascript faster. Every person have specific way and method to give an answer and Every question have probably multiple ways of an answer. So I tried to give you an answer with jQuery. I just help out to you.

Comment: @andy Event it's not about downvote but give me reason what did you find wrong with snippet from your point of view?

Comment: "If you downvote then give me a reason" - I didn't downvote you so I'm sure I don't need to give you a reason. I did find your use of jQuery problematic tho for the reason I gave earlier.